# G-equivariant derived functors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $k$ and $G$ a group acting on $X$. Considering the derived category of $G$-equivariant coherent sheaves $D^b_G(X)$ and $G$-equivariant derived functors. Under what kind of assuptions on $G$ one can expect that the $G$-equivariant functors are just taking invariants of the orinary ones? If $G$ is finite and $\mathrm{char}(k)$ does not divide the order of $G$ this should be true.

Comment: Which particular functors do you have in mind?

Comment: I was thinking about Ext, $\mathcal{E}xt$, $\mathcal{T}or$, or even Fourier-Mukai transforms, etc.

Comment: It is true in the case when $G$ is finite. See Section 4 in 'Mukai implies McKay'.